# Filter by name and include column headers if they contain a value

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following data:

[image: Sample Data]

and would like to create a separate sheet that would Identify the First name, Last name and the header of columns E:N if they have  a value of `1`.

I would like to have the separate sheet include a dropdown list of names in column A1 to populate the data.

Answer (score 1):

UNTESTED (what, with that much data and in a barely legible image ?!)

Copy the entire populated part of your spreadsheet below existing data (say to A100) and fill the central area (starting E101) with:

```
 =if(E2=1,E$1,"")
```

Count row contents with:

```
=countunique(E101:N101)
```

in O101 and fill down to suit.

In your other sheet:

```
 =FILTER({Sheet!A101:B201,Sheet!E101:S201},Sheet!O101:O201>0)
```

Comment: sorry here's  the sample sheet: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jwgDuByKjzrLFu3emdYzhlFRQVQ_jsDYIr5X64htNuw

Comment: I changed : =FILTER({Sheet!A101:B201,Sheet!E101:S201},Sheet!O101:O201>0) to =FILTER({Sheet1!B101:C201,Sheet1!E101:FP201},Sheet1!FQ101:FQ201>0) Because this is the whole table

Comment: I would like to be able to pull data for one teacher (first name and last name name) Column B:C and  the column headers that have a value.

Comment: This is new to me not sure what the transpose process would look like.

Comment: I can use the following formula to give me the first column name that contains a value using: =ArrayFormula(INDEX($E$1:$FP$1,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(E2:FP2),0)))

Comment: I would like to be able to select a teachers name and populate all the columns that the has attended.

Comment: I did that I copied and paste the data on the same sheet starting with A100

Comment: If I use the following formula how can I change it to show all column header names that the teacher has attended  each of the columns have a 1 if they attended. =ArrayFormula(INDEX($E$1:$FP$1,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(E2:FP2),0)))